# DataFrame: how to draw a 3D graph using Index and Columns as x and y, and data as z?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

My DataFrame line index and column index store `x` and `y` values, while the data values are `z` values, i.e. `f(x, y)`.

Let's take an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[150, 120, 170], [190, 160, 130]],
                  index=[2, 4], columns=[10, 30, 70])
print(df)
#     10   30   70
# 2  150  120  170
# 4  190  160  130
```

then `f(4, 30)` is `160`.

I would like to make a 3D plot of function `f`. I don't really mind if it looks like a 3D histogram or a surface plot - both answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) from your row and col indices and then you can use [`plot_surface`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=plot_surface#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_surface):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame([[150, 120, 170], [190, 160, 130]],
                  index=[2, 4], columns=[10, 30, 70])
x,y = np.meshgrid(df.columns, df.index)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.plot_surface(x, y, df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but the above code does not output any result on my machine. How do you get this graph displayed?

Comment: You need to add `plt.show()` to show the plot unless you're working with IPython (sorry, I forgot to mention)